# Expand and select a field from a Navigation property which of type collection in Breeze

Tags: entity-framework, odata, breeze

I have 3 classes in EF as follows

```
  Public class ClasssA
      {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ClassBId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ClassB> ClassB { get; set; }
      }

   Public class ClassB
      {
        public int Id { get; set; }

         public int ClassCId { get; set; }

        public virtual ClassC ClassC { get; set; }
      }

  Public class ClassC
      {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public String Value {get; set; }
      }
```

While firing a odata request from browser,it works fine.

```
http://localhost:8090/odata/ControllerName?$expand=ClassB/ClassC&$select=ClassB/ClassC/Value
```

But can anybody tell me how can I do in breeze query?
since `ClassB` navigation property is a of type collection and each of it contains `ClassC` navigation property.
How can I select a property inside `ClassC` with this type of navigation?

*In simple my question is how to access a property inside, by expanding a Navigation Property of type Collection (in Breeze)?*

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is supported by BreezeJS. You are welcome to add it to [our UserVoice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions)